# How can I query ListView records that were created by users?

Tags: soql, list-view

When logging in as a user I can see that they have `ListView`'s that I can't find programatically (I'm a System Administrator). Using the Id of the `ListView` in the URL when logging in as that user, I looked for the list view in the following ways

**QUERIES:**

`SELECT CreatedBy.Name,CreatedDate,DeveloperName,Id,LastViewedDate,Name FROM ListView`

`SELECT CreatedBy.Name,CreatedDate,DeveloperName,Id,LastViewedDate,Name FROM ListView USING SCOPE EVERYTHING`

(The `ListView` returned records, but only public list views)

`SELECT Id FROM UserListView`

`SLECT Id FROM UserListView USING SCOPE EVERYTHING`

(The `UserListView` qeuries returned no records)

**REST EXPLORER:**

`/services/data/v45.0/sobjects/ListView/00B1Y000007ErH0` where `00B1Y000007ErH0` is the Id I found while logging in as the user.

(I got a resource not found error)

**BULK API:**

I exported the entire `ListView` table via the bulk API but got the same results as the `ListView` queries above. The `UserListView` was not available via the bulk API.

---

I looked through the questions and answers of the following posts and did not find my answer.

- [How can I get the selected listview id (or name) without using javascript](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/115370/how-can-i-get-the-selected-listview-id-or-name-without-using-javascript)
- [How to read a ListView (restricted Visibility to me) with APEX MetadataService.cls?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/68524/how-to-read-a-listview-restricted-visibility-to-me-with-apex-metadataservice-c)
- [How to retrieve what filters were set on a listview using API?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/102373/how-to-retrieve-what-filters-were-set-on-a-listview-using-api)
- [Retrieve/Deploy a custom metadata type's list view?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/218051/retrieve-deploy-a-custom-metadata-types-list-view)
- [Parsing ListViews columns from the Metadata API](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/40243/parsing-listviews-columns-from-the-metadata-api)
- [Access ListView via REST API](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/14438/access-listview-via-rest-api)
- [Deploy/Download Profile ListView](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/126633/deploy-download-profile-listview)
- [how to get listview query by passing the listview Id?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/119741/how-to-get-listview-query-by-passing-the-listview-id)

---

Has anyone had any success programatically accessing `ListView`'s that users have created? I need to do some auditing on what kind of views they are creating.

**EDIT:**

In the [metadata documentation for list views](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_listview.htm) I noticed it says

> List views with the Visible only to me Restrict Visibility option are not accessible in Metadata API. Each of these list views is associated with a particular user.
>   I wonder if that applies to more than just the metadata api and is completely inaccessible without logging in as each user.

Comment: As another user, there is no way to query any `ListView` record where the person creating it selected "Visible only to me". There is no exception.

Comment: Can you add that as an answer so I can choose it as the answer in a few days?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As another user, there is no way to query any `ListView` record where the person creating it selected "Visible only to me". As you already found, the `Metadata API` makes this clear, and there are no exceptions in other APIs either.

Comment: I ended up logging in to all 50 users and manually moving their list views to public views